# DynamicReports: How to import the libraries to use with NetBeans in a new project?

Tags: java, dynamic-reports

How do I import DynamicReports library to a netBeans project?

http://www.dynamicreports.org/getting_started.html#step9

I found this link:

http://www.dynamicreports.org/documentation/documentation.html#examples_netbeans

But it shows how to import existing examples. If I want to build a dynamic report from scratch i.e. a new project instead of an existing one, in NetBeans, how do I import DynamicReports libraries after I have downloaded dynamicreports-3.1.0-project-with-dependencies?

For example if I use iText I can do as below:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMVx3MIUApU

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the ANSWER:

Create a new project : Go to Libraries -> Add Jar/Folder then copy all files from dynamicreports-3.1.0\dist and dynamicreports-3.1.0\lib

Answer (score 0):

**How to run the examples in Netbeans**
Download [dynamicreports-5.0.0-project-with-dependencies from the download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dynamicreports/files/dynamicreports)
Copy

- /examples/netbeans/dynamicreports-examples

  from the archive to your NetBeansProjects folder e.g.
- /NetBeansProjects/dynamicreports-examples

Copy all files from /lib and /dist folders from the archive to

- /NetBeansProjects/dynamicreports_examples/lib/

Run NetBeans and open the project
Build the project